# Where should one hit an AT-ST Walker to do the most damage?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

Recently when fighting an [AT-ST Walker](http://battlefront.wikia.com/wiki/AT-ST/DICE) it appeared to take more damage per blaster shot on the legs than than the "head" of the walker.  Similar to how the [AT-AT walker](http://battlefront.wikia.com/wiki/AT-AT/DICE) takes more damage on different parts of the larger walker.
[image: AT-ST Walker]
That leads me to wonder, what part of the AT-ST walker is most vulnerable?

If one can hit the walker anywhere on its surface, where can one do the most damage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The AT-ST has a weak spot on its back, try to target this when
>   attacking one and defend it when piloting.

[image: The AT-ST has a weak spot on its back, try to target this when attacking one and defend it when piloting]

Shoot those exhaust ports. Always the weak spot in imperial tech. :-)  But seriously, anywhere in the back panel (back of the "head") is the "weak spot."

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The back, specially the head is also a big weak spot for villans and heros.

Comment: The question appears to be about the AT-ST Walker, not heroes.